# How to build DocC documentation from CLI

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcodebuild, docc

So I have been browsing the web for a while now and can't seem to find an answer on how to build the **native DocC Xcode documentation** *using a CLI command*.

Both the `xcodebuild` commands and Fastlane do not provide a command to build the documentation - as far as I know.

The docs are supposed to be built **inside a CI/CD Github Actions workflow**. If there are other methods to accomplish this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple has added a new command to `xcodebuild` tools:

```sh
xcodebuild docbuild
```

You can also take a look at the WWDC presentation "Host and automate your DocC documentation". Start watching from **7:06 min** onwards for DocC automation: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10236/

Answer (score 4):

## Host and Automate your DocC documentation ☁️

### Tl;dr

I tweaked the `xcodebuild docbuild` for modular projects as below:

```
xcodebuild -project ModularSlothCreator.xcodeproj -derivedDataPath docsData -scheme ModularSlothCreator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 13 Pro Max' -parallelizeTargets docbuild
```

I also tweaked the `docc` site generation using the `transform-for-static-hosting` flag:

```
$(xcrun --find docc) process-archive transform-for-static-hosting "$ARCHIVE" --hosting-base-path ModularSlothCreator/$ARCHIVE_NAME --output-path docs/$ARCHIVE_NAME
```

### BONUS: Automate DocC with GitHub Pages and CI

I've updated the original demo showcased at WWDC with support for **static hosting** of *modular* **App** targets (rather than only supporting a single Swift Package announced at WWDC) using GitHub Pages without needing to define a server configuration for convenience in my [blog post](https://medium.com/kinandcartacreated/host-and-automate-your-docc-documentation-c6ac29dc0feb).

Answer (score 3):

To complement the initial answer, I'd like to mention this [complete summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/nota11y/2021/21docC/#automating) of all the WWDC21 videos regarding DocC that contains precious information about automation.

Indeed, there's a **feature in Xcode 13** for building documentation through the command line that includes the **docbuild action** with many possible options as described below. 
[image]
Besides, **Xcode 14** fosters the DocC archive content [deployment at the root of a web server](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/nota11y/2022/22SwiftDocC/#publishing) thanks to its new **compatibility with most web servers**.  
[image]

Even if a solution has already been provided by @Colin , I deemed it important to append some information that may be crucial for some.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub [apple/swift-docc Getting Started with DocC](https://github.com/apple/swift-docc?tab=readme-ov-file#getting-started-with-docc) provides Command Line Interface (CLI) information for Swift-DocC standalone documentation.

```sh
### For Linux/macOS Swift Toolchain based installations:
docc --help

### For Xcode based installations:
xcrun docc --help

# OVERVIEW: Documentation Compiler: compile, analyze, and preview documentation.
# 
# USAGE: docc <subcommand>
# 
# OPTIONS:
#   -h, --help              Show help information.
# 
# SUBCOMMANDS:
#   convert                 Converts documentation from a source bundle.
#   index                   Create an index for the documentation from compiled data.
#   preview                 Previews documentation from a source bundle.
#   process-archive         Perform operations on DocC Archives.
# 
#   See 'docc help <subcommand>' for detailed help.
```