# How can I publish on GitHub using Docc?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, docc

I have an SPM package hosted at `https://github.com/janodev/foobar`.

How can I generate documentation with Docc and host it at GitHub?

Comment: Apple updated DocC to include apps and static hosting. Check out my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71952338/4995828)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. **Install Xcode 13.3**
2. **Add Swift-DocC as a dependency**

```swift
let package = Package(
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v15), .macOS(.v12)
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "git@github.com:apple/swift-docc-plugin.git", branch: "main"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // ...
    ]
)
```

3. **Enable page publishing**

- In your GitHub repository go to Settings > Pages
- Select Branch:main, folder: /docs
- Click Save

4. **Generate docs**

```sh
# note this is for GitHub hosting, with a specific target and base path 'Foobar'

# don’t forget to build or you’ll get blank pages
swift build

# parameter values are case-sensitive!
swift package \
 --allow-writing-to-directory ./docs \
 generate-documentation \
 --target Foobar \
 --output-path ./docs \
 --transform-for-static-hosting \
 --hosting-base-path foobar
```

Or, if the package contains iOS frameworks, run this instead:

```swift
xcodebuild build -scheme Foobar -destination generic/platform=iOS

xcodebuild docbuild -scheme Foobar \
-destination generic/platform=iOS \
OTHER_DOCC_FLAGS="--transform-for-static-hosting --output-path docs --hosting-base-path foobar"
```

5. **Push the generated documentation**

This means pushing the `docs` directory to the GitHub repo. It may take a minute, or several, and your browser cache may deceive you, but it should appear at:

```sh
#       username          repository           target
https://janodev.github.io/foobar/documentation/foobar
```

Note that my repository name was lowercase so I used `-hosting-base-path foobar`. The target path component, however, is always lowercase, Idk why.

---

For any troubleshooting check the bug database:

- [Swift-DocC](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-15965?jql=project%20%3D%20SR%20AND%20component%20%3D%20Swift-DocC)
- [Swift-DocC-Render](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-15915?jql=project%20%3D%20SR%20AND%20component%20%3D%20Swift-DocC-Render)

Comment: I’m the author of a Swift library that’s available via SPM, and I’ve recently added DocC docs to it. If I want to host these docs on GH Pages and follow your steps, does that mean that anyone using my library then has to download swift-docc-plugin as well? We don’t have “dev dependencies”, right?

Comment: Oh wait, not if I don’t actually add it as a dependency to my target I assume.

Comment: Correct. You add it to the package dependencies but you don’t add it to any target.